# Inter app communication on IOS

Tags: ios, iphone

In IOS, it is possible to launch another app from your app using a URL scheme. 
But is it possible to have it then return to the calling app if the home button is then pressed?

What if Guided Access is enabled?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What research have you done?  Any code spikes to show?

Comment: Thanks. Only what I've read on the web. Although I've coded for Macs I haven't done anything on IOS. From what I read, I thought it wasn't possible, but thought I'd try here in case I'd missed something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No sorry, The Home button will always lead to the users home, there is no way for developers to override that.

You can however have a button in the "called" app that will take the user back to the app that opened it. Facebook does this when going back and forth between their main app and their messages app.

*edit* Good answer from @shim about guided access in the comments. Basically if its on, you won't be able to leave the app so it doesn't do any good with this problem. */edit*

Comment: Any idea what the effect of calling another app is when Guided Access is enabled on your app?

Comment: If guided access is on, it won't let you exit the app. It's pretty easy to test... Just find an app that can link to another app (e.g. apple maps links to transit option apps, email opens links, maps opens phone calls etc) and turn on Guided Access while using it. You won't be able to leave the app.

Comment: Answer as well as the Comment. Excellent, +1.